# Adds an header row on top of a table with bold equation using kableExtra and rendering it in quarto

Tags: r, latex, quarto, kableextra, tinytex

I am making a table with `kableExtra` version 1.3.4 in a beamer presentation with `quarto` version 1.4.274 using the following code and installing `tinytex` version 0.46 with `tinytex::install_tinytex()`:

```
library(tibble)
library(kableExtra)

payoff_ultimatum <- tibble(participante = c('Receptor', 'Receptor'),
                           oferta = c('Acepta', 'Rechaza'),
                           pagos = c('$((1- \\lambda)N, \\lambda N)$', '$(0,0)$'))

payoff_ultimatum |> 
  kbl(col.names = c('', '', '$\\lambda \\in [0,1]$'), 
      format = 'latex', align = 'c', booktabs = TRUE, 
      escape = FALSE) |>
  kable_styling() |>
  column_spec(column = c(1, 2), bold = TRUE) |> 
  collapse_rows(columns = 1, valign = 'middle') |> 
  add_header_above(header = c(' ' = 2, 'Proponente' = 1),
                   align = 'c',
                   bold = TRUE)
```

I get the following result:

[image]

I want to make bold the header which contains the desire [equation](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?%5Clambda%5Cin%5B0,1%5D) like [this](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?%5Cboldsymbol%7B%5Clambda%5Cin%5B0,1%5D%7D). I try the following code including in the `YALM` the related package `\usepackage{bm}`:

````
---
format: 
  beamer:
    include-in-header:
      - text: |
          \usepackage{booktabs}
          \usepackage{longtable}
          \usepackage{array}
          \usepackage{multirow}
          \usepackage{wrapfig}
          \usepackage{float}
          \usepackage{colortbl}
          \usepackage{pdflscape}
          \usepackage{tabu}
          \usepackage{threeparttable}
          \usepackage{threeparttablex}
          \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
          \usepackage{makecell}
          \usepackage{xcolor}
          \usepackage{bm}
---

# Teoría de juegos

```{r}
library(tibble)
library(kableExtra)

payoff_ultimatum <- tibble(participante = c('Receptor', 'Receptor'),
                           oferta = c('Acepta', 'Rechaza'),
                           pagos = c('$((1- \\lambda)N, \\lambda N)$', '$(0,0)$'))

payoff_ultimatum |> 
  kbl(col.names = c('', '', '$\\boldsymbol{\\lambda \\in [0,1]}$'), 
      format = 'latex', align = 'c', booktabs = TRUE, 
      escape = FALSE) |>
  kable_styling() |>
  column_spec(column = c(1, 2), bold = TRUE) |> 
  collapse_rows(columns = 1, valign = 'middle') |> 
  add_header_above(header = c(' ' = 2, 'Proponente' = 1),
                   align = 'c',
                   bold = TRUE)
```
````

But I get the following error `! Improper alphabetic constant. <to be read again> \mitlambda`. I am not and expert in `latex` but the following code works which is what `kableExtra` version 1.3.4 and `quarto` version 1.4.274 are using in relation to the table I am trying to build:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Teoría de juegos}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{>{}c>{}cc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{ }} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Proponente}} \\
\cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){3-3}
 &  & $\boldsymbol{\lambda\in[0,1]}$\\
\midrule
 & \textbf{Acepta} & $((1- \lambda)N, \lambda N)$\\
\cmidrule{2-3}
\multirow{-2}{*}{\centering\arraybackslash \textbf{Receptor}} & \textbf{Rechaza} & $(0,0)$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Anyone knows how can I render this table with a bold equation in the header using `quarto` without getting errors as in the case of `latex`?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you really should no longer use the tabu package, see https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu/blob/main/README.md#note-about-the-status-of-this-code

Comment: Thank you for the observation but I don't use latex directly because I need to integrate many tools like r, python, latex, markdown and quarto. The package is used in kableExtra version 1.3.4 for latex as you can see [here](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf) in the section **LaTeX packages used in this package**. The author and maintainer, Hao Zhu, will have good reasons to use it even if it is not actively maintained by its original author since 2011. However I really appreciate your observation because you have help me with your posts and comments in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use poor man's bold: `$\\pmb{\\lambda \\in [0,1]}$`

[image]

Comment: Thank you Julian for your help. A really appreciate your solution. I really don't use latex directly so it is nice to know people  who knows r, quarto and latex.